# Sending data via retrofit in android studio

Tags: android, list, android-studio, post, retrofit

I have following request that I have to send

[image]

I am using retrofit.

```
 @Headers("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("UIP/load_shedding_scheduling")
Call<UIPResponse> loadShedding(
        @Header("transactionid") String tid,
        @Header("privatekey") String pk,
        @Body ArrayList list
        );
```

**Request Class**

```
public class LoadSheddingRequest {

@SerializedName("global_device_id")
@Expose
private String globalDeviceId;
@SerializedName("request_datetime")
@Expose
private String requestDateTime;
@SerializedName("start_datetime")
@Expose
private String startDateTime;
@SerializedName("end_datetime")
@Expose
private String endDateTime;

@SerializedName("load_shedding_slabs")
@Expose
private List<Slabs> slabs = null;

public String getGlobalDeviceId() {
    return globalDeviceId;
}

public void setGlobalDeviceId(String globalDeviceId) {
    this.globalDeviceId = globalDeviceId;
}

public String getRequestDateTime() {
    return requestDateTime;
}

public void setRequestDateTime(String startDateTime) {
    this.startDateTime = startDateTime;
}

public String getStartDateTime() {
    return startDateTime;
}

public void setStartDateTime(String startDateTime)
{
    this.startDateTime = startDateTime;
}

public String getEndDateTime()
{
    return endDateTime;
}

public void setEndDateTime(String endDateTime)
{
    this.endDateTime = endDateTime;
}

public List<Slabs> getSlabs() {
    return slabs;
}

public void setSlabs(List<Slabs> slabs) {
    this.slabs = slabs;
}
}
```

**Slab Class**

```
public class Slabs
{

@SerializedName("action_time")
@Expose
private String actionTime;
@SerializedName("relay_operate")
@Expose
private String relayOperate;


public String getActionTime() {
    return actionTime;
}

public void setActionTime(String actionTime) {
    this.actionTime = actionTime;
}

public String getRelayOperate() {
    return relayOperate;
}

public void setRelayOperate(String relayOperate) {
    this.relayOperate = relayOperate;
}




}
```

I ma not sure that is this approach is right or not. I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43114344/8919244) and make exactly like it.

```
 ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            arrayList.add(actTime);
            arrayList.add(selectedCommand);
            arrayList.add(actTime2);
            arrayList.add(selectedCommand2);

LoadSheddingRequest request = new LoadSheddingRequest();
            request.setGlobalDeviceId(global_device_id);
            request.setRequestDateTime(time);
            request.setStartDateTime(startTime);
            request.setEndDateTime(endTime);
            request.setSlabs(arrayList);
```

It's giving error at `setSlabs`. Also I have no idea that I am doing it correctly or not

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's right.
Just change parameter for the body `@Body ArrayList list` to `@Body LoadSheddingRequest requestBody` then pass the request body object in arguments.

And what error is it giving at `setSlabs`?

Comment: `error: incompatible types: ArrayList<String> cannot be converted to List<Slabs>
                request.setSlabs(arrayList);` is the error

Comment: It is because the argument type of setter is List<String> and you're passing ArrayList<String>. So change the  argument type to `ArrayList<String>`